# Set selected value in multiple select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this multi select list:

```
<select id="vendors" name="vendors" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
    <option value="4">D</option>
    <option value="5">E</option>
</select>
```

When the page loads, I'm loading a list of ids that need to be selected in my select list. Here's how I'm trying to do it:

```
var vendors = GetVendorArray();  // list of vendor ids I want selected

$.each(vendors, function(index, item) {
    $("#vendors").filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() == item; 
    }).attr('selected', true);
});
```

But this doesn't work, none of the items are being selected. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Show us the contents of the `vendors` object

Comment: @nbrooks - the array has data. It's pulling in a list of ids from the query string. I have an alert when I loop through each value in the array that displays the item

Comment: You say 'list of ids' but that means nothing to me...none of your options has an id-attribute. I ask because there might be some issue with blank space characters in the string, you might be trying to match against value when you're really trying to match against text, I don't know...without seeing that we can't tell if that may be a part of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) reduces the set of matched elements to match the additional selector/callback fn. output. You need to target the `<option>` elements, not the drop-down list itself, since you're trying to select the option based on whether its value matches your array contents.

```
var vendors = GetVendorArray();  // list of vendor ids I want selected

$.each(vendors, function(index, item) {

    //you're filtering options, not the list itself
    $("#vendors > option").filter( function() {
        return $(this).val() == item; 
    }).prop('selected', true); //use .prop, not .attr
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Simplest approach is just pass the whole array as value to the `select` using `val()`. With `mulitple select` value is an array

```
$('#vendors').val(  GetVendorArray())
```

DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/sPKAY/

The problem with approach you took was not looping over `option` tags